# Swift in Objective-c project: not supported for static libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to import a swift file from https://github.com/codestergit/SweetAlert-iOS/blob/master/SweetAlert/SweetAlert.swift into an existing objective-c project.

After adding the file to the project I try to compile (just adding the file without doing anything else) and I get the following build error:

```
Swift is not supported for static libraries
```

I'm new to swift, and don't see how this library is marked as static and what I should do to change it and make it compile - I don't need it to be static.

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to either add the Swift file to a framework or an application.

Due to problems with importing Swift information from static libraries, Apple hasn't implemented building and linking static libraries that have Swift code.

Comment: What I ended up doing is to create a framework that contains the Swift file and having my static library use that framework, therefor having access to all features of my Swift file.

Answer (score 0):

> just adding the file without doing anything else

I don't know what you added or where you added it. But what you want to do is add *just* the *SweetAlert.swift* file — nothing else — and you want to add it *to your project* as part of *your app target*.

You will then also need to accept the dialog that creates a bridging header, and import the hidden bridging header into your Objective-C code that wants to call this code.

Comment: Do you need more help? Post your project on github and I'll fix it for you. Or if you like, I can post an example on github for you.

Comment: Ooooh, it may be that _your project_ already contains a static library. In that case, yes, you won't be able to incorporate the Swift file into it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem occur because you use the swift code for the objective-c project.you will find the file under podsTarget pods/XXXX/XXX  is swift file.
 for example use pod 'ReactiveCocoa','2.1.8'instead of pod 'ReactiveCocoa'

Answer (score 0):

The current runtime doesn't ship with the OS, so static libs would lead to multiple runtimes in the final executable.
See more  https://twitter.com/owensd/status/555060783407591424