# How can I make an appcelerator ios native module with Swift?

Tags: swift, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I need to use the ios-charts module coded in Swift in a TiUIView, but when I try to generate the native appcelerator module I can't because it generates a static library and Swift can't be used to do that, only is used to generate dynamics libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've hit a sensitive issue here. Since the Titanium module is a static library it cannot contain swift code (that's xCode limitation not titanium). You can see my question about it here: [Swift in Objective-c project: not supported for static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528709/swift-in-objective-c-project-not-supported-for-static-libraries)

What you would have to do is wrap your swift code in a framework and link that framework in your Titanium module project.

Comment: Correct, but Swift support IS coming though http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/08/ios-9-and-android-m-day-one-support/

Comment: @RenePot would also be able to use swift code from Hyperloop. But if you currently want to implement swift I'm afraid that's your only option right now.

Comment: I created the .framework and enable _EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT_. It gives me the following warning :  `Not running swift-stdlib-tool: EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT is enabled, but the product type 'Static Library' is not a wrapper type`.

Comment: I get this when I try to run my appcelerator project with the native module: `[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Intermediates/PruebaSinImportancia.build/Debug-iphoneos/PruebaSinImportancia.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PruebaSinImportancia normal arm64
[ERROR] :   Ld build/Intermediates/PruebaSinImportancia.build/Debug-iphoneos/PruebaSinImportancia.build/Objects-normal/armv7/PruebaSinImportancia normal armv7
[ERROR] :  (2 failures)
2016-01-15T17:41:06.826Z | TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
2016-01-15T17:41:06.827Z `